# Is the Impulse-Momentum Theorem True?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum

This is just a general question I want to throw out there, and see arguments from both sides... Is Impulse-Momentum Theorem True?

Well in my opinion I would say yes because it is a derived equation:

$$\text{Impulse} = \text{Force} \times \text{Time},$$
or
$$Δp = F \times \delta t.$$

Comment: ... and the argument from the other side is? We call it a theorem for a reason.

Comment: I dont know... Theorm's are not facts... @EmilioPisanty

Comment: Indeed, they're not facts, they're 'if, then' statements. In this case, if classical mechanics hold (i.e. if your experiment is within its range of validity) then it holds, period. There is no 'argument from both sides' (though if you have a source that says otherwise, quote it and we can explain why it's wrong), so there isn't much point to the question as stated.

Comment: Im not a physican(im horrible at physics), so my point is probably false.. @EmilioPisanty

Answer (score 2):

If it is represented as *Newton's Second Law* (where *p* is taken to be *relativistic linear momentum*,) then it is an *exact* theorem. However, the way it is cast is *not* exact because it is not marginalized over time, *t*.

Instead, if you say *F(t)=dp/dt* with *p* being *relativistic*, then it would be *exact* assuming *F* is the spatial component of *4-force* vector in the context of *relativity*.